# Oracle 10g express GUI client?

Tags: oracle, user-interface, ubuntu, oracle-xe, database-administration

Are there any free Oracle 10g express GUI clients? I'd be looking for an app that has similar functionality to phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked at [sqldeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index-098778.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

I quite like DbVisualiser ( http://www.dbvis.com/ ), which is a JDBC based tool and seems to work well with most databases I've worked with. It may serve your needs, though it seems they have now changed to a business model based on a free crippled version and a licensed personal edition which has all the features.

Answer (score 0):

[TOra](http://torasql.com/about) is available for Linux, Windows, and Mac OS X. It is open source under the GPL.

<s>Also, Oracle (I believe XE as well) comes with their Enterprise Manager; have you tried http://database-hostname:1158/em ?</s> edit: Apparently XE does not come with the Enterprise Manager, but if this is for development, you may be able to use the full Oracle software under their [developer license](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/standard-license-088383.html), then you can use the Enterprise Manager.

Comment: Enterprise Manager isn't part of XE. It did come with its own management app as part of the built in Apex 2.1. But Apex 2.1 is so old now it is the first thing people upgrade, losing the management app